# How do I programmatically set constraint with specific distance?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a button in my layout and I would like to specifically set it to SafeArea.bottom = button.bottom + 28. I am having errors when I try using

```swift
btnAddRecord.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
btnAddRecord.bottomAnchor.constraint.equalTo(self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 66).isActive = true
```

I am getting an error 'Reference to member 'equalTo' cannot be resolved without a contextual type'

May I know where I am going wrong and how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: try with button..translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: Edit your question to include the error messages.

Comment: There is no such thing as `equalTo(constraint:`. Delete `constraint:`. There is no such thing as `view.bottom` either. Try `view.bottomAnchor`.

Comment: Sigh. There's no `constraint.equalTo`. It's `constraint(equalTo:`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is wrong, Try This :

```
 btnAddRecord.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 btnAddRecord.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -28).isActive = true
```

Also view.bottomAnchor refer to superview and not safeArea , for setting it relative to safe area , you need to do like this :

```
 btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -28).isActive = true
```

28 negative will put it above the safe area.

Answer (score -1):

translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints needs to be set as false.

Code Be like:

```
yourButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
yourButton.bottomAnchor.constraint.equalTo(constraint: view.bottom, constant: 28)
```

Comment: check your button reference is it properly referred with view ?

Comment: take a button properly and make an outlet with the view class . then use the solution . I hope it will work